# How do I choose the "date_popup" widget for custom date field from code?

Tags: 7, datetime

I have a custom field in a custom form element which is declared using the following code:

```
$element['data_da'] = array(
  '#type' => 'date',
  '#title' => t('Date from'),
  '#default_value' => isset($items[$delta]['data_da']) ? $items[$delta]['data_da'] : NULL,
  '#description' => t('Description for field Date from'),
);
```

When I insert data, I see three selects, one for year, one form month and one for day. I would like to use the "date_popup" widget.
How can I do that? What should I set?
Is there a '#widget' directive?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you install the version 2.x of the [Date](http://drupal.org/project/date) module, you will be able to use more form fields, including a "date_popup" field, which shows a pop-up to select the date.
The module has an option that allows the user to decide if the pop-up should be shown; if you want to override that option, you should use `variable_set('date_popup_timepicker', 'default')`. That is the default option used by the module, but if the user selects "none," then the pop-up will not appear.

About setting a custom format with the "date_popup" field, the form field uses the "#date_format" attribute that, in the development snapshot 7.x-2.x, is said to accept most of the formats. The default value for that attribute is the one returned by `variable_get('date_format_short', 'm/d/Y - H:i')`.
The complete list of the attributes used by the form field, reported in a comment for the `date_popup_element_info()` documentation is the following one:

- "#date_timezone"
  The local timezone to be used to create this date.
- "#date_format"
  Unlike earlier versions of this popup, most formats will work.
- "#date_increment"
  Increment minutes and seconds by this amount, default is 1.
- "#date_year_range"
  The number of years to go back and forward in a year selector, default is -3:+3 (3 back and 3 forward).

Drupal core modules have only the "date" form field, and it doesn't use any "#widget" attribute. Third-party modules could define new attributes, though; as far as I know, no module defines "#widget" as attribute for form fields.

Comment: Actually i'm using the Date module, i'd like to use the simple datepicker and set the format to dd/mm/YYYY. I f i choose date_popup it also shows a timepicker. And i don't know how to set the format (it defaults to mm/dd/YYYY

Comment: I expanded my answer to report how to set a custom format.

Comment: http://kali-dasan.blogspot.in/2014/06/drupal-date-popup-custom-form.html - Here I have explained with example.

Comment: Is there any chances to set min and max date in #datepicker_options ?

Comment: @Guru As far as I can see, no. #datepicker_options is for jQuery picker options.

Comment: But we set defined as below: '#datepicker_options' => array('maxDate' => 30),