# date popup field

Tags: forms

how to implement a date field in my forms using the form API. I actually wanted a date popup field.
I have use this code

```
$form['dob'] = array(
  '#type' => 'date_popup',
  '#title' => t('DOB'),
  '#date_format' => 'Y-m-d',
  '#date_year_range' => '-100:+0',
);
```

but it does not work..

Comment: --> How did u manage to solve it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you would need to install the date module for date popup to work.

the following answer on stackoverflow has more details

[How do I choose the "date_popup" widget for custom date field from code?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/7759/how-do-i-choose-the-date-popup-widget-for-custom-date-field-from-code)

Comment: i have install the model and see this link but it still show me this error Undefined index: #id in theme_date_popup() (line 675 of all\modules\date\date_popup\date_popup.module).

Comment: are you using the same format as aove? and where are placing it?

Comment: yes I have using the same format as above .  in my custom module

Comment: could you show be the full function that you have placed this in?

Comment: function _menu_example_menu_page {$form['dob'] = array(
  '#type' => 'date_popup',
  '#title' => t('DOB'),
  '#date_format' => 'Y-m-d',
  '#date_year_range' => '-100:+0',
);  return $form; } do you have skype??? this my name (rasha.shareef) on skype could you add me :)